# How to make TableView Cells different sizes horizontally and vertically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

How do I make my Table View look something more like this instead of just standard horizontal cells. I want it to look like the example images put below, what do I need to do? My code for my tableView is down below as well.

[image]
[image]

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import SDWebImage

struct postStruct {
    let title : String!
    let author : String!
    let date : String!
    let article : String!
    let downloadURL : String!

}

class NewsViewController: UITableViewController {
    var posts = [postStruct]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Posts")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot.childrenCount)
        for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            guard let value = rest.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> else { continue }
            guard let  title = value["Title"] as? String else { continue }
            guard let  downloadURL = value["Download URL"] as? String else { continue }
            guard let  author = value["Author"] as? String else { continue }
            guard let  date = value["Date"] as? String else { continue }
            guard let  article = value["Article"] as? String else { continue }

            let post = postStruct(title: title, author: author, date: date, article: article, downloadURL: downloadURL)
            self.posts.append(post)
        }
        self.posts = self.posts.reversed(); self.tableView.reloadData()
    })  
}

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].title
        let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
        let post = self.posts[indexPath.row];
        imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: post.downloadURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
        return cell!
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "detail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let destVC = segue.destination as! DetailNewsViewController
                destVC.titleText =  posts[indexPath.row].title
                destVC.dateText =  posts[indexPath.row].date
                destVC.authorText =  posts[indexPath.row].author
                destVC.bodyText =  posts[indexPath.row].article
                destVC.headerPhoto =  posts[indexPath.row].downloadURL
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `CollectionView` with `flowLayout` you will get this type of Listing ,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use different Cells with different identifier in your storyboard. Design each cell as you want and in use cell rowAtIndexPath return the cell you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use UICollectionView instead of tableView. And create your custom layout. See this great tutorial to understand custom layouts. 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest